# Could not load type 'CwizBankApp.HomeLogin'

Tags: asp.net

I dont know what could be missing here but I keep getting this error ,

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'CwizBankApp.HomeLogin'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HomeLogin.aspx.cs" Inherits="CwizBankApp.HomeLogin" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Source File: /HomeLogin.aspx    Line: 1 

Here is the code behind file

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;  

namespace CwizBankApp
{
    public partial class HomeLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Membership.DeleteUser("ppp002");

            if (Request.QueryString["session"] =="new_session")
            {
                Session.Abandon();
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Response.Redirect("/HomeLogin.aspx");


            }
            //Useful when using role based access because if an authenticated user is sent here that means he is trying to view a page he is not allowed to
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
            {
                Response.Redirect("/UnauthorizedAccess.aspx");

            }



        }

        protected void cmdLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
            {
                HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(txtUsername.Text, false);
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration, ticket.IsPersistent, "");
                authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
                Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
                GetUserName(); 
                string redirUrl = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtUsername.Text, false);
                Response.Redirect(redirUrl);

            }


        }
        public void GetUserName()
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext dt = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var name =( from nm in dt.Users_AdditionalInfos
                        where nm.UserCode== txtUsername.Text.Trim() 
                        select nm).Single();
           Global.UserName=name.FirstName +" "+ name.LastName; 
        }

        protected void cmdCreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Response.Redirect("/CreateAccount.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Also I checked that under my project's bin folder the dll is not there , can anybody help me out with this.
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Please show the code behind as well. It should have a namespace of CwizBankApp and the class name should be HomeLogin otherwise it will not be able to find the code.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you build it?

Comment: @KevinMain , ya I get errors and that is because I have applied some CSS3 styling to some of my controls.

Comment: Does it build successfully or does it fail? If it fails the dll is not built hence it can't find the code and the error above.

Comment: @KevinMain you are right , it was showing build failed , hence the problem , I rectified some of the errors and then the build succeeded and now it works well , thanks a lot.Can you post an answer so that I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the namespace is CwizBankApp and the class name is HomeLogin.

Now rebuild - does the build succeed or fail? If it fails the dll will not get created and hence you get the error, check all the error messages and fix the problems and then rebuild.